# voltage regulators: How does Ohm's law apply here (and how not to fry an ams1117)

Tags: voltage-regulator, current-limiting, ohms-law

Very basic noob question here, asking for an analogy rather than a 'it's law xy':

I used an ams1117, 2.5V, *sot223*. To test it, I used an usb cable 5V and plugged it into my phone charger (rated 2A) and measured the output of the IC: it quickly overheated (no measurement taken). **I should mention the connectors got so hot it even desoldered one of the cables: the green one, connected to the ams1117** (this is how I inferred it overheated).  Basically the question is, why is testing your IC this way silly or suboptimal.

It was my understanding that when you regulate / fix the voltage in a circuit (i.e. the output of a voltage regulator, set to 2.5V, such as this ams1117), the current will be basically 'regulated by the resistance'. Here, I guess the resistance would be only the wires and the IC, as nothing else besides the multimeter was attached.

Did this overheat because the resistance was low, and due to the inverse relationship between current and resistance? If no, please point out my misconceptions.

**Edit:** sorry for the horrific picture below (I didn't know how to do this best). Legend: Ams is ams1117 2.5V out, usb is a usb cable with ground and 5v separated (power supply quick charge, up to 2A). MM is multimeter in voltage mode, auto, dc. Red is Vin, Green Vout, black ground.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, without a load the power drawn would be minimal.  What measurement did you make?  Did you by chance **improperly short the regulator output to ground with an ammeter?**  That's not how an ammeter is used...

Comment: A linear voltage regulator (like the AMS1117) connected with no load should not overheat. How did you connect it (schematic)?

Comment: Your multimeter wasn't set to measurrent current was it? Multimeters act as a short-circuit between their terminals in current measurement mode.

Comment: Show us a schematic or photo. You must have connected something up wrong.

Comment: Looks like you were using the TO-252 package? The datasheet says this regulator requires the use of an appropriate output capacitor for stability, but I'm not sure if that would cause an LDO to overheat when there was no load present.

Comment: it was a sot223 apparently. I added some more info

Comment: You marked best answer. Did you find the issue?

Comment: @DKNguyen I marked your answer correct because, if I understand everything correctly here, I draw the following conclusions that lead me to believe this was merely an unintended short circuit:
1) **the circuit diagram does not show any short circuit and is correct to test the IC** 2) there was therefore likely an unintended, undepicted short circuit, involving the Vout connection of the ams (green wire in picture). 3) the IC would not have gotten so hot as to desolder one of the connections if it was attached correctly, with this power supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do not say what you were using as a load or how much current you were drawing.

Second Ohm's law DOES NOT apply here. I mean, you could imagine the linear regulator as a variable resistor that continuously adjusts itself based on the combination of input voltage, output voltage, and instantaneous current to drop exactly the correct amount of voltage across itself to keep the output voltage the same, but it is kind of useless. So don't do it. It has too many modifications and stipulations to be useful.

Trying to think of a linear regulator as a resistor is a bit trying to think of a round wheel as a square where the distance between the center of the wheel and the ground constantly adjusts to maintain the same distance as it rolls.

Linear regulators burn off all the extra voltage as heat. That means:

- the input voltage must always be higher than the output voltage,
- the input current is the same as the output current,
- and the higher the input voltage relative to the output voltage the
  more heat is made.

So in your example, 5V in and 2.5V out would be 2.5V difference. Suppose you were drawing just 250mA (you never told us what your load was or how much current you were pulling), then the power dissipated would be:

(5V - 2.5V) * 250mA = 625mW

In the AMS1117 datasheet, the largest package available is listed as heating up 80C/W. So it would heatup 50C above ambient. That's hot. And that's with the largest package. The smallest package heats up 160C/W which is 100C above ambient.

Comment: ...but the asker doesn't describe loading the regulator with anything, so it should only draw its only quiescent current and not even get warm

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, I am awaiting further clarification.

Comment: thank you for these kind elaborations that helps me to understand and calculate this better. I think the only sensible explanation I have is the one of Chris, which is, it might have been a short circuit. This would explain the high temperature - if it desolders that would be >150°C?

Comment: Desoldering is at least 180C. It would have fried before then.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage regulators are mainly made of diodes or zener diodes.

Diodes and zener diodes are not linear components and therefore they don't obey Ohm's law.