# Understanding thermoelectric generator and Ohm's law

Tags: voltage-regulator, current-source, peltier, voltage-source

I understand the simple terms of `U = R * I` in the context of a constant voltage - which is approximately the case for most consumer electronics, where the resistance of the load (in a closed circuit) determines how much current is drawn.

However, if the source of electricity is *not* constant voltage, (e.g. a thermoelectric generator, TEG1-12611, [datasheet](https://thermoelectric-generator.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/SpecTEG1-12611-6.0Thermoelectric-generator1.pdf)) and both `I` and `U` change, and it's unclear to me what happens if you simply attach a load (e.g. a voltage regulator of 3V, ams1117, ca max ~5V/1A) and a simple LED (max ratings 3V, 20ma). **How do I calculate at what point would my components fry, due to overcurrent or overvoltage** (if my source is powerful enough)?

Example circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLWhMa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Intuitively, I would try to find an IC that generates a constant voltage output (from variable current and voltage source) and don't overthink it, but I'm actually interested in understanding this.

Sorry if the question is a bit basic, I couldn't find an answer with the topic of Peltier modules.

Comment: Instead of describing a circuit in words (which is very ambiguous), draw a schematic but not like the one when you posted [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/532512/voltage-regulators-how-does-ohms-law-apply-here-and-how-not-to-fry-an-ams1117). A proper one please. No ambiguity.

Comment: Ohm's law only applies to resistors. It doesn't apply to voltage regulators, LEDs, or thermoelectric modules.

Comment: I'm going to disagree that Ohm's Laws doesn't apply outside of the specific case of resistive circuits.  Ohm's Law applies even to the things you've listed as well as just about everywhere else.

Comment: @jwh20 Ohm's Law, by definition, only applies to devices (usually denoted as resistors) for which the current through the device is proportional to the voltage across it. The constant of proportionality is called resistance. Unfortunately, it has been applied in a more general sense since its inception.

Comment: Added schematic, please note I used the battery symbol for Peltier module (for lack of anything better). Moreover, please note the values may not be precisely exact because I'm really aiming to understand how to think about a circuit like this rather than the specific examples of included components (more specifically, calculate exceeding maximum ratings of arbitrary components in the closed circuit)

Comment: What limits the LED current?

Comment: @Andyaka I don't know, in practice attaching a standard LED in the Arduino kit without resistor may not have been the best practice, but it worked reliably for any time I powered one... (if you like, you can suggest an arbitrary resistor that makes sense in this context, and I'll add it, especially if that makes the calculations easier?)

Answer (score 3):

You can treat the TEG as an equivalent source of x volts with a series resistance of R.

According to the first chart, under realistic operating conditions, the open-circuit voltage will not exceed about 8.5V typically, well within the 18V recommended for the AMS1117.

If your objective is to extract the maximum output power, then pay attention to the last graph. All the situations will have that characteristic, just for different optimum loads.

How you use the information depends on what you are trying to calculate. If  you know the operating conditions then  you can figure out the optimum loading to get the most power out, the maximum voltage and the voltage at any current. Let's assume you have Th = 250°C and Tc = 50°C. You can just about get 3.3V out at optimum loading, which is about 2.75A, way more than that regulator can handle. The TEG appears as a 6.5V source (first graph) with less than 1.15 ohms in series (second graph). Remember that the 'matched' load resistance equals the source resistance for maximum power transfer.

With a 0.5A loading, the voltage should rise to 6V - 0.5*1.15 = 5.4V so your 3.3V linear regulator will be dissipating about 1W.

In practice it may be difficult to maintain those thermal conditions due to the large heat flow across the TEG, but that's outside the scope of this answer.

P.S. One would expect the heat flow to be slightly affected by the loading (more load current = more heat loss) as it acts like a TEC, but if we premise the calculation on the *temperatures* then that is not important. This is analogous to a generator that is harder to turn as the load current increases, but it's far more pronounced in a generator because of the roughly order of magnitude higher efficiency.